# getting first saturday in specific date and year

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

i have code in php,the function of first saturday in this month

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$dt             = new DateTime('first Saturday of this month');
$periode        = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

it's mean that the result is first saturday of this month(july), but i want to get first saturday of january 2015,so i change my code being

```
$dt             = new DateTime('first Saturday of January 2015');
```

but it has wrong result. help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), also see [the ref in PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('first sat of jan 2015'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately programming languages like PHP don't process natural language like this (at least not reliably. if it works you wouldn't be asking this question). You will have to formulate your function differently to get a more deterministic result.

I have answered your other question, which is almost identical to this one, but here it is again:

```
function stamp_of_first_saturday($year,$mon){
  $base=mktime(0,0,0,$mon,1,$year);
  $dow=date('w',$base);
  $sat=(6-$dow)*3600*24+$base;
  return $sat;
}

echo date('Y-n-j', stamp_of_first_saturday(2015,7) );
```

Comment: You should see [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) documentation and be amazed ;)

Comment: Yes @vhu, thanks for pointing this out. I was more than amazed when I first saw it and felt uncomfortable because of its language parsing nature and potential issue with locale settings. Will use it only as last resort.